# What do the RTT numbers mean in a TraceRoute result?

Tags: ping, networking

I have this traceroute [result](http://networking.ringofsaturn.com/Tools/traceroute.php), and I am wondering what EXACTLY do the 3 numbers mean at the end of each line?  I assume they are ping times, but what exactly is the difference between each number?

```
 1  L300.DLLSTX-VFTTP-49.verizon-gni.net (71.123.238.1)  9.429 ms  9.867 ms  10.095 ms
 2  G0-1-849.DLLSTX-LCR-08.verizon-gni.net (130.81.107.110)  10.075 ms  9.887 ms  10.075 ms
 3  so-6-2-0-0.DFW01-BB-RTR2.verizon-gni.net (130.81.28.210)  28.547 ms  39.649 ms  9.992 ms
 4  0.ae2.BR1.DFW13.ALTER.NET (152.63.2.149)  10.110 ms  9.298 ms  10.109 ms
 5  * * *
 6  ae-2-70.edge4.Dallas3.Level3.net (4.69.145.77)  *  9.798 ms  10.115 ms
 7  ORACLE-CORP.edge4.Dallas3.Level3.net (4.59.32.6)  10.093 ms  9.374 ms  10.100 ms
 8  adcq7-swi-7-xe-0-1-0.oracle.com (141.146.0.129)  10.310 ms  11.980 ms  12.480 ms
 9  ora-141-146-3-31.oracle.com (141.146.3.31)  12.458 ms  12.190 ms  12.629 ms
10  bigip-www-adc.oracle.com (141.146.9.91) [open]  12.353 ms  2947.212 ms *
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

RTT is "round-trip time", it's the delay between sending the packet and getting the response; the `*`s mean that the timeout was reached before getting a response.

Three numbers are provided from three different packets to give you a better sampling of the delay to that host.

Comment: +1 yes, the results from three packets are provided so that you can spot variation in results. Often troublesome networks won't show up in the results of a single packet. If you're running Linux I *really* recommend the 'mtr' package for traceroutes.

Comment: I second that, just that `mtr-tiny` might be better as it doesn't depend on X (especially when you need to debug remotely over ssh where there's no GUI available)

Comment: Thanks to all for clarifying that.  I couldn't find an answer to that anywhere.